# Onmouseout transition with animation

Tags: css, animation, transition

I'm trying to animate a div on mouseout with keyframes animation :

```css
div{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-animation:flipInY 2s;
}

div:hover{
    -webkit-animation: flipInY 0.8s;
}
```

So when the user mouseout there will be some transition,but i want to do this using animation keyframes not with normal transition:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flipInY {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
    }

    70% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful?

Comment: The problem is that when i mouseout the animation reverse with no transition :D and i want to have some nice transition when the mouse distances from the div ,but using kwyframes